# Cowin api get beneficiary issue

Tags: api, bearer-token

I followed below step to get beneficiaries.

Generated OTP - from https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/generateOTP
Confirmed OTP - after converting to sha256 - https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/auth/public/confirmOTP
#2 generated bearer token which i have used to find beneficiaries - https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/beneficiaries
#3 gives unauth error - I think the bearer token which is generated from above is not correct.

I tried to fetch the token from cowin.gov.in website (after giving mobile no and confirm otp) and used that token generated from response of confirming otp, this time it worked.

Why generating bearer token is not correct from https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin/cowin-public-v2?
also I checked the api in cowin website is validateMobileOTP vs the one mentioned in https://apisetu.gov.in/public/marketplace/api/cowin/cowin-public-v2#/ is confirmOTP which one we should use?

Answer (score 0):

To get Bearer token

```
var authorizationToken = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("userToken").match(/"([^"]+)"/)[1];
```

after getting token, set it to

```
XMLHttpRequest xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("authorization", authorizationToken);
```